# MongoDB Stitch Document insertion not passing through Schema check

Tags: mongodb-stitch

In Stitch -> rules, I open up `MyCollection`, clicked on the Schema tab, and typed the following:

```
{
  "bsonType": "object",
  "required": [
    "roadmapTitle"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "roadmapTitle": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "creatorId": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    }
  }
}
```

Saved & Deployed. However, if I insert a document like `MyCollection.insertOne({nothing here: "hehe"})`, the Log shows okay, the object is stored, no error is caught. Interestingly though, running the validate function next to "edit schema" in the Schema field shows that all of those documents failed schema validation. Did I miss a step in enforcing the Schema validation on document insertion?

Comment: Highly likely because I ran the tests as system user instead of a normal user. System user can bypass Schema

Comment: Previous comment confirmed, Schema Validation performs expectedly.